# Python 3 relative imports or running modules from within packages... which to abandon?

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, package

I'll first begin by stating that I have been coming back to this problem over and over again for the last several months. No matter how much I research into it, I cannot seem to find a satisfactory answer. I'm hoping that the community here can help me out.

Basic problem - consider this structure of python packages and python modules.

```
|- src
    |- pkg_1
        |- foo_1.py
        |- foo_2.py
        |- __init__.py
    |- pkg2
        |- bar_1.py
        |- bar_2.py
        |- __init__.py
    |- do_stuff.py
    |- __init__.py
```

Suppose that module `bar_2` needs to import from module `foo_1`. My options are myriad, but a few present themselves quickly.

(My preferred way) Module `bar_2` can do `from ..pkg_1 import foo_1`. This is great because it doesn't require what amounts to hard-coding a path into the module, thereby allowing flexibility, ease of maintenance, all that. In `do_stuff.py` if I then write `from src.pkg_2 import bar_2` and then run, I am golden.  Here is an example setup:

foo_1.py:

```
class Foo_1():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello from foo_1!')
```

bar_2.py:

```
from ..pkg_1 import foo_1

class Bar_2():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello from bar_2!')
        foo_1.Foo_1() #Prints foo_1 message!
```

do_stuff.py:

```
from src.pkg_2 import bar_2

bar_2.Bar_2()
```

Console prints:

```
Hello from bar_2!
Hello from foo_1!
```

All is well.  However, consider the next scenario.

Suppose now that I want to run `bar_2` as `__main__`, as follows:

```
from ..pkg_1 import foo_1

class Bar_2():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello from bar_2!')
        foo_1.Foo_1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bar_2()
```

A `SystemError` is raised: `from ..pkg_1 import foo_1
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

For far longer than I care to admit, I did not understand the reason for this.  The solution, though, lies in the fact that when you run a module directly, its `__name__` variable is set to `__main__`. Since the relative imports establish position in the hierarchy with `__name__`, this means that there is no directory information to parse to figure things out.  This makes loads of sense, and I feel very dumb for having not realized it before.

So, thus began my quest (yeah, just getting started).  Eventually I learned of the `__package__` variable.  Reading about it in the PEP notes, it seemed as though it would solve all my problems!  So I tried the following boilerplate code before the import statements in `bar_2`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    __package__ = 'src.pkg_2'
```

This did not work.  :(

I since have come to find out that Guido has addressed this very issue and that he regards the whole notion of running a module from within a package as anti-pattern.

See this link:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html

This makes sense, as I will be the first to admit that I only do it for on the fly testing... which should never be done! (Right??)  Therefore, as best as I understand, there are no elegant ways to run the module from within a package UNLESS you do absolute imports... which I would like to avoid.

So, after all of that, here is my question: Should I use one of the *many* hacky ways out there to get around this problem and do unholy things with the system path so that I can have my relative import cake and eat it (i.e. test on the fly by running as `__main__`) too??  I think I already know the answer (I just would like some wizened Yoda-like person to confirm).

Possible Answer:

1. Use relative imports, because hard-coding paths (and hard-coding in general if avoidable) is ant-pattern.
2. Do not bother with running modules nested in packages as `__main__`... instead, run them from your testing module (which you wrote first... right??).

Thank you for taking the time to read this question.  I realize there are many other questions regarding this topic... but I wanted to 'share my journey' and see if my current course of action is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Running the following in `src/`:

```
python -m pkg2.bar_2
```

will have `pkg2/bar_2.py` be your main script while still being inside a package, meaning that relative imports will work.

Comment: So you would open a console in the directory and run this command?

Comment: Or create a desktop entry or shortcut that has that as the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

I follow these rules which prevent any issues:

- Always use full imports, no relative imports.
- Always start a Python process from the root of the project or using the full absolute path.

It's rather rare that you benefit from relative imports when you have to move files around (and when you do, it's not that much work to rename a few import lines).

Full paths from the root of a project or using the full path on disk of a file removes any ambiguity and will run the desired file.

Answer (score 1):

My answer (and that of many CPython core developers) is essentially the same as Simeon's.  The only thing not hard-coded by relative imports is the name of the package ('src', in this case).  But you hard-coded it in do_stuff.py anyway.  Within-subpackage relative imports (unlike the cross-subpackage imports you exhibit) let you copy the subpackage to another package (with a different name), and possibly change the subpackage name as you do so.  Do you really need that particular flexibility?  Is it really worth more than the very real cost of relative imports?

Why the subpackages, instead of putting everything in the main package, src?  Idlelib has about 60 run-time modules in idlelib/ itself.  The only subpackage is idle_test, for test modules.  All imports start with idlelib.

I am a big fan of being able to run the test for one module (rather than the package test suite) by running non-cli modules as the main module. It encourages incremental TDD.  So I have 'if **name**.. ' clauses in both run-time and test modules in idlelib.